# How to disable SSH from GitHub repository and using only HTTPS for push and fetch?

Tags: android-studio, github, ssh-keys

I have created repository on my GitHub account and successfully added my android studio project to it last week

I could push and pull with no issue but suddenly GitHub doesn't allow me to clone repository URL from android studio or push or pull the project

After hours of investigation I understood that a public key for SSH is needed

[image: the error]

[image]
I even created that with git command lines and copied it in GitHub settings, but still have same problem.

1- Why I could work with GitHub but now I can't?

2- How to disable SSH from GitHub repository and using only HTTPS for push and fetch?

3- What is the best solution for this? I just want to push / pull the project.

** New explanation **

I did what @VonC said but no change on URLs :
By the way, I use Android Studio

[image: terminal]

I did push then get this error :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by @VonC help

- I created ssh public key in my **bin** terminal in windows 10.
- I added that to my github acount/settings.
- ( just need to be checked) I get authorized in **bin** terminal (windows):
  MINGW64 /bin $ ssh -T git@github.com
  Enter passphrase for key : XXX
  ... Hi tahadev! You've successfully
  authenticated

Then

I did this command in **Android Studio terminal** :

```
  "git remote set-url origin git@github.com:tahadev/Native_Form_Android.git"
```

Then

(By the way it is weird why it shows HTTPS url when setting for SSH)
 "git remote -v" 
   origin  https://github.com/tahadev/Native_Form_Android.git (fetch)
   origin  https://github.com/tahadev/Native_Form_Android.git (push)

Then I did PULL first then PUSH, in some back/force :) I finally could be able to reach my code in git from Android Studio

Thx @VonC

***Android Studio terminal code and bin terminal***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find strange that the first push error message mentions "`Git@github.com`": only `git@github.com` could work, not `Git`.

But in any case, if you want to experiment with HTTPS without changing anything, type anywhere:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
```

Then check again how a push works in VSCode.

To revert:

```
git config --global --unset-all url.https://github.com/.insteadof
```

---

That `insteadOf` setting would *not* change a `git remote -v` output (still SSH there)
If would simply ensure to use an HTTPS URL when doing a `git push`.

Comment: thx @VonC 

I do exactly what you said but nothing changes 
I added an image to question check that please

Comment: @tahaDev Yes, that is expected: the remote URL will not change statically. It will change on runtime when you push.

Comment: when I do push i get this error 
I cant add error here its too long , check the question please

Comment: I am using VPN (I need to use it all the time) may that be problem for ssh public key?

Comment: @tahaDev That is possible (was it working before? With SSH and VPN?). Would you see an HTTPS URL used if you typed git push in the terminal?

Comment: I could be able to use it for first or second day it didn't need any SSH or public key 
I could push and fetch with no issue

Comment: @tahaDev Not sure what has changed then. DOes the git push works form the terminal? (where you did the insteadOf setting)

Comment: In my "android studio" terminal

Comment: @tahaDev Exactly: does it work in that "Android Studio" terminal? Meaning is the git push showiing an HTTPS URL instead if an SSH one?

Comment: no, when I use this commad : "git remote -v"  it returns SSL url , you can check it in image I sent (terminal one)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/arRok.png

Comment: I created  ssh public key in my bin terminal in windows 10, I added that to my github acout/settings 

I get authorized in bin terminal also:
TENTH02+programmer@TENTH02 MINGW64 /bin
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/programmer/.ssh/id_rsa':
Hi tahadev! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. 

I dont know why I cant push or clone url

Comment: one weird thing happened 

C:\LOGIICO_PRG\Native_Form_Android-master>git remote set-url origin  git@github.com:tahadev/Native_Form_Android.git

C:\LOGIICO_PRG\Native_Form_Android-master>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/tahadev/Native_Form_Android.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/tahadev/Native_Form_Android.git (push)


(I am sorry for the content) I did "git remote set-url origin" for SSH url but  git remote -v gives me HTTPS